# Convert SQL CREATE TABLE query to Drupal Content Type

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I know there is the [Content Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/cck) for Drupal, which provides a useful UI for adding new Content Types in Drupal. However, I find it hideously slow and painful to create large new content types.

**reason**

I want to create a Content Type so I can convert all data to being a node, and therefore expose it to Views and be able to have a good UI for updating nodes.

**possible?**

1. Is there any module that will "convert" an sql query into it's `hook_form()` equiv?
2. Will hook_form() expose it to Views?
3. Any others ideas?

Cheers

Gary

---

**just one example of 100s of table sql query to be converted**
*imagine the the pain; the sleepless nights, the tripping over the bundles of hair on the floor of creating each field in CCK*

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `file_author` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `file_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `file_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `file_name` text NOT NULL,
  `file_file` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `file_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `file_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `downloads` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `file_date` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `file_review` text NOT NULL,
  `screenshot` text NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(12) NOT NULL default '0',
  `update_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `author_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `sub_author` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `version` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `mirc_version` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `reviewer` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `posted` int(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`file_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `file_author` (`file_author`),
  KEY `file_type` (`file_type`),
  KEY `downloads` (`downloads`),
  KEY `file_date` (`file_date`),
  KEY `updated` (`updated`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4544 DEFAULT
```

Comment: i'm in the exact same situation; what did you end up doing to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The hook_form() is not really a hook but nonetheless it's just generating forms, it's not handling the storage.

If you want to manage a custom storage to avoid CCK you will have to declare your tables through the [schema API](http://drupal.org/node/146843) and then handle the actions you want to perform in the hook_nodeapi() or the submit callback automatically invoked.

Good luck for your quest.

Comment: Will this expose it to Views?

Comment: To expose data to views you will have to implement other hooks like hook_views_data(). http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing data you want to access from Drupal (Views), I recommend one of these solutions:

1. Create CCK content types and import your data using the [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate)
2. Make the data available to Views using the [Table Wizard module](http://drupal.org/project/tw)

Comment: Point is, I don't want to go through the CCK GUI and create every field. It's tedious clicking "add," moving onto the next page, inputting details, etc. Table wizard isn't an option because it's not been ported to Drupal 7, and the "supersded" Data module isn't D7 compatible either. I'm not asking for a point and click solution, I don't mind a bit of coding, but rewriting all my mysql tables for drupal schema... come on, surely there is a module out there?!

Comment: Right, I see. A while ago, I needed a content type with a lot of similar fields, but I didn't want to go through all the clicking either. I created a content type and added only one field of every type. Next I exported the content type to code, duplicated the fields in a text editor (making sure that each field has a unique name) and imported it back into Drupal. Maybe that works for you too...